# Octopress deployment to gh-pages

Tags: git, bitbucket, jekyll, octopress, github-pages

I made a `username.github.io` repo and I pushed my current Octopress blog files into the `master` branch so that I can track the changes I made to the whole blog.

Next, I want it to appear in the `gh-pages` branch so I used `rake setup_github_pages`, then `rake generate` and `rake deploy[gh-pages]` but git rejected it with the following message:

```
To https://github.com/username/username.github.io
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/username.github.io'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

## Github Pages deploy complete
cd -
```

How do I solve this? I only want to put the `_deploy` folder in the `gh-pages` and the rest in the `master` branch.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution thanks to Tomoya Hirano of [NiceCabbage](http://nicecabbage.com).

In his [Octopress and gh-pages post](http://www.nicecabbage.com/blog/2012/03/04/blogging-for-rubyists/) he mentioned using [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com) as the repository for the actual Octopress source code instead of using GitHub.

I find this solution very convenient since my GitHub repo for the Octopress blog now contains the `_deploy` folder while the rest is in BitBucket. It's really not the exact answer but this workaround addresses the separation of `_deploy` and the rest's upload somewhere secure in the Interwebz.

**Hope this helps someone!**